# mongoosastic index not getting deleted after removing document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Currently i am using mongoose Model.remove method to remove a document. But after removing document mongoosastic index still contains deleted document index.

```
User.remove({_id:userId}, function(err) {
   if (err) {
      res.json({success:false});
   }
   else {
      res.json({success:true})
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this section in [mongoosastic documentation](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#removing-a-document):

> Note that use of Model.remove does not involve mongoose documents as outlined in the documentation. Therefore, the following will not unindex the document.

`User.remove({_id: userId})` does not trigger mongoosastic unindex.

Instead you can easily find the user and call `.remove()` on it. Here is how it'll look like:

```
User.findById(userId, function(error, user) {
   user.remove(function(err) {
      if (err) {
         res.json({success:false});
      }
      else {
         res.json({success:true})
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its still a pending issue in 2019, just do a direct delete using an HTTP call.

I use the ff

```
 await  fetch('http://localhost:9200/put_index_here/put_type_here/doc_id_here', { method: 'DELETE', body:'' });
```